# Creating a page offset with CSS

Tags: html, css, frame, offset

So, I'm attempting to offset this html by 300 pixels, from the top and the left. None of the things I've tried so far have worked, but if you know of a page that could help me, I'd be very interested to read it...I've already got three frames in that I want to keep here, and I'm trying to create an offset with "pagediv", but no dice.

I've stolen the frame layout (pirate pride), as I have limited CSS experience. Again, I've been fiddling with it to try and make it appear 300 pixels down and to the right of the top left corner of the window.

But it won't budge! How would you do it? Please keep in mind that I can only insert html into my host's editor--it's quite a bad one. I can't manage my own files on the server. Oh! yes. And ideally, the frames that I'm using to offset would be clear--because the place where I'm putting this HTML already has all kinds of menus and crazy business to the left and above that I don't want to cover up.

```
   <!--Force IE6 into quirks mode with this comment tag-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Drive: CSS Left and Right Frames Layout</title>
<style type="text/css">



body{
padding-top:200px;padding-left:200px;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
}

#pagediv{
padding-top:300px;
padding-left:300px;
}

#framecontentLeft, #framecontentRight{
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 300px; /*Width of left frame div*/
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: white;
color: black;
}

#framecontentRight{
left: auto;
right: 0; 
width: 250px; /*Width of right frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: white;
color: black;
}

#maincontent{
position: fixed; 
top: 0;
left: 250px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
right: 300px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
}


innertube{
margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

* html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
padding: 0 150px 0 200px; /*Set value to (0 WidthOfRightFrameDiv 0 WidthOfLeftFrameDiv)*/
}

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}


</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
/*** Temporary text filler function. Remove when deploying template. ***/
var gibberish=["This is a test page for a gym", "We wholly believe in the art of strength", "Ipso liptum facto freako."]
function filltext(words){
for (var i=0; i<words; i++)
document.write(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+" ")
}
</script>


</head>

<body>

<Font face = "helvetica">

<div id = "pagediv">
<div class = "innertube">

<div id="framecontentLeft">
<div class="innertube">

<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<h1>Videos</h1>


</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="video sample.png" width="200" height="200" />


</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="video sample.png" width="200" height="200" />


</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="video sample.png" width="200" height="200" />


</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>

<div id="framecontentRight">
<div class="innertube">


<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td align="left" valign="top"><h1><b> Location: </b></h1> <br />

<iframe width="200" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=2110+Pine+St.+Abilene,+TX+79601&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=77.57349,131.132813&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=2110+Pine+St,+Abilene,+Texas+79601&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=32.473249,-99.731684&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=2110+Pine+St.+Abilene,+TX+79601&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=77.57349,131.132813&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=2110+Pine+St,+Abilene,+Texas+79601&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=32.473249,-99.731684" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small> <br />
Art of Strength Abilene @ Hendrick Heatlh Club <br />
2110 Pine St. Abilene, TX 79601 <br />
(325) 670-7682
 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">


<h1> Contact </h1>
Phone : 1 390 232 2323 <br />
Email : abeline@aos.com <br />
Website : Link

</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="advertisement1.jpg" width="150" height="250" />


</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="advertisement1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />


</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<img src="advertisement1.jpg" width="175" height="100" />


</td></tr>





</table>

<

</div>
</div>


<div id="maincontent">
<div class="innertube">
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<h1>About AOS Abeline, Texas </h1>
<p><script type="text/javascript">filltext(25)</script></p>


</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<h1>Our Training</h1>
<p><script type="text/javascript">filltext(300)</script></p>
<img src="../../Documents/punch/new aos site/Screen shot 2011-12-07 at 10.12.27 AM.png" width="307" height="243" />


</td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top">

<h1>Staff</h1>
<p><script type="text/javascript">filltext(10)</script></p>


</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</FONT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `body{padding-top:300px;padding-left:300px;}` or `body{margin-top:300px;margin-left:300px;}` instead of the zero values?

Comment: If by that you mean just adding it in to the body section of the CSS, then yes, I've just tried it--the first one causes everything to align left, getting rid of the frames. And the second one doesn't seem to affect anything...sorry.

Comment: Towards the bottom of your code, after about 175 lines, there's a stray `<`.  Also, you have a font tag.  Don't use the font tag, apply fonts with CSS.  That's not your problem with positioning - it's just waaay out of date.  Finally... did you *want* quirks mode?  That's something I try to avoid.

Comment: Ah, Surreal, thanks for the info. I've fixed the <. I'm not sure what Quirks mode is. I really don't know very much about CSS. To me it just looks like a series of hash tables with various settings. It's a markup language, right? But I'll look up quirks mode and get back to you...

Comment: Quirks mode is an IE mode - it means it renders things its own way, not the standard way.  I always try to stay away from it.  CSS is your styling markup to alter the look of the page.  The idea is to build the page with HTML and make it look like you want with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`position:absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute-positioning) and [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#fixed-positioning).

See the section  [6.6. Choosing a positioning scheme: ‘position’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#position-property):

> **absolute**: The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the ‘top’, ‘right’, ‘bottom’, and ‘left’ properties. These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings. Though absolutely positioned boxes may have margins, those margins do not collapse with any other margins.
>
> **fixed**:
>       The box's position is calculated according to the "absolute" model, but in addition, the box is fixed with respect to some reference. As with the "absolute" model, the box's margins do not collapse with any other margins. In the case of handheld, projection, screen, tty, and tv media types, the box is fixed with respect to the viewport and does not move when scrolled.

So a new block won't help you at all, since `position:absolute` doesn't care about it. You have to set a block to `position:relative` and give it a margin, although this won't fix your `position:fixed` as "the box is fixed with respect to the viewport and does not move when scrolled". The following CSS code will fix your errors, however, your HTML code is a horrid mixture of evil things, shape and polish it. Don't pirate copy bad code. Learn the language. Shine. And use a [[X]HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

```
body{
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:200px;
    position:absolute;

    top:0; left:0; bottom:0;right:0;

    font-family:Helvetica;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#framecontentLeft, #framecontentRight, #maincontent{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
}
#framecontentLeft,#framecontentRight{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#framecontentLeft{
    left: 0; 
    width: 300px; /*Width of left frame div*/
}

#framecontentRight{
    right: 0; 
    width: 250px; /*Width of right frame div*/  
}

#maincontent{
    left: 250px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 300px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    bottom: 0;
}

.innertube{
    margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

* html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
    padding: 0 150px 0 200px; /*Set value to (0 WidthOfRightFrameDiv 0 WidthOfLeftFrameDiv)*/
}

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Ah! You are a diety. Thanks for the help. I understand what the problem is--and I agree that my pirating code is a symptom, not a cause, of the ugly code. I shall be more shiny in the future. Here is your [pixel bicycle] (http://imgur.com/bVpPG)

Answer (score 0):

In general you should have one DIV that wraps everything. Then you apply `margin-top` and `margin-left` to that DIV.

Comment: Hm...I'm going to have to look into how DIVs work, as right now I'm not sure how I could do that without disrupting the layout of the frames. Good to know, though!

Comment: Wait, what you're saying doesn't seem to make sense. Why would they make a tag that allows you to denote different sections if you should only use one of them per page?

Comment: @user1222151: He said *one*, not *only one*. So just create *another* div, which contains the rest of your site ;).

Comment: Hmm...I've added    #pagediv{
padding-top:300px;
padding-left:300px;
} to the CSS style, and added an extra div with that ID into the HTML, but no dice. I'll update the original code so that you can see what I've done...I've probably done something obviously silly. Thanks for continuing to help out